# How many ways are their to place $15$ stones into $6$ boxes?

Tags: combinatorics

The motivation for this problem comes from the game of backgammon.

Problem:
$15$ identical pieces are to be placed into $6$ different bins. How many ways are there to place the pieces.
Note: The bins are numbered.

Note: Empty bins are allowed.

Answer:

Let $c$ be the number we are looking for. If the pieces were unique, then I claim:
$$ c = 6^{15} $$
However, they are not. When I first tired working on this problem I thought the  answer was:
$$ c = \dfrac{6^{15} } { 15!} $$
However, that turns out to be a number less than $1$. What is the right way to solve this problem?

Comment: Are boxes numbered or identical?

Comment: The boxes are numbered.

Comment: For future similar questions, [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) are your friend.

Comment: As everyone has rightfully so commented, you have to use the "stars and bars" method. But I want you to think about this problem : how many ways are there to place 15 **labelled** stones into 6 **labelled** boxes so that each box must be non-empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on  whether or not empty boxes are allowed.

If empty boxes are not allowed then the answer is $ 14 \choose 5 $. To see this let's represent for example the situation (5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 2) as follows:
$15 = 1 + 1 + 1+ 1+ 1 | + 1 + 1 + 1+ 1+ 1 |+1 | + 1| + 1 | + 1 + 1 $. The $|$ symbol represents the place where the next box starts. You need to choose 5 places between $1$'s from 14  available  ones  to place your $|$ symbols.

If empty boxes are allowed then you do almost the same thing. Now you can't just choose 5 out of 14 places for $|$ because you can have two or more of these symbols in a row. But you have 20 places where you must put objects of two types: $+1$ or $|$ (fifteen $+1's$ and five $|$). If you choose 5 (out of 20) places to put $|$ then the places for $+1$ are chosen automatically. So in this case the answer is $20 \choose 5$.

Edit: it's a very standard method and I've finally remembered it's name in English to give you a link, here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the answer of Vladislav, and will present an alternative perspective on the problem.

For Stars and Bars theory, see
[this article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) and
[this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

You have $~15~$ identical pieces to go into $~6~$ distinguishable bins.

Instead of placing the *pieces into the bins*, 
**assign the bins to the pieces.**

Then, the bins are distinguishable, and the pieces are not distinguishable.

Consider the number of solutions to

- $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_6 = 15.$
- $x_1, ~x_2, ~\cdots, ~x_6 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

Here, $~x_i~$ refers to the number of (indistinguishable) pieces assigned to the (distinguishable) bin-$i$.

Per Stars and Bars theory, the number of solutions is 
$~\displaystyle \binom{15 + [6-1]}{6-1} = \binom{20}{5} = 15504.$

---

If non-empty boxes were not allowed, you could employ the change of variable $~y_i = x_i - 1 ~: ~i \in \{1,2,\cdots,6\}.$

Then, you would be enumerating the number of solutions to

- $y_1 + y_2 + \cdots + y_6 = 15 - 6 = 9.$
- $y_1, ~y_2, ~\cdots, ~y_6 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

Here, the number of solutions is 
$~\displaystyle \binom{9 + [6-1]}{6-1} = \binom{14}{5} = 2002.$